# How to check query using if and else

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables in database in which the first table consist of freelancer section second table of client and 3 in which when client selects an freelancer the 3 table store id of freelancer and id of client.
Now i want to check if there is no shortlisted freelancer then all of them must be shown on webpage but if some are shortlisted.
They must not be visible while other must be shown but using if and else condition for the same returning else contdition always
here is my query part

```
$c_email = $_SESSION['c_email']; //client_email

//if there is not any candidate in the shortlist_freelancers w.r.t particular job then show all the data
$queryForShortlisted = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `shortlist_freelancers` where `shortlist_job_id` IN
 (select `postJob_id` from `client_detail` where `client_email` ='abcd@gmail.com')");

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0)

{
  echo "1"; //for testing
    $querystart = "SELECT * FROM `freelancer_detail` WHERE f_id NOT IN
     (SELECT f.f_id FROM `freelancer_konnect_detail` f INNER JOIN shortlist_freelancers s ON f.f_id = s.shortlist_freelancer_id
      AND s.shortlist_job_id IN( select postJob_id from `client_detail` where client_email = '{$_SESSION['client_email']}' ))
       AND status = 1"; }

 else
  {
   echo "not shortlisted";
     $querystart = "SELECT * FROM `freelancer_detail` WHERE status = '1'";//if candidates are  not shortlisted
 }
```

If there are shortlisted freelancers then also it is showing else part
thanks

Comment: did you try pasting you query manually in phpMyadmin section "sql" tab of your database? and do you get any result?

Comment: in phpmyadmin the result is correct

Comment: How can we write this code in prepared statement it throws boolean result error while doing same using prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a variable in every query when you select the query then that variable must activate and compare that variable in the condition statements, then place the code what you want to display in the body of that condition.